# What is the value of O(n) + O(n-1) + O(n-2) + ... + O(1)? Is it O(n^2)? How?

Tags: big-o

I have with me a recursion of the form,

```
T(n) = T(n-1) + O(n)
```

which should be equivalent to

```
T(n) = T(1) + O(2) + O(3) + .... + O(n-1) + O(n)
```

so my solution depends on the value of

```
O(n) + O(n-1) + O(n-2) + ... + O(1)
```

Since, `n + n-1 + n-2 + ... + 1 = n*(n+1)/2`, I feel this should be `O(n^2)` but I am not sure how to use the Big-O maths to come at this solution.

I mean,

```
c * O(n) is O(n)
```

but

```
n * O(n) is O(n^2)
```

How do I conclude that

```
O(n) + O(n-1) + O(n-2) + ... + O(1) = O(n^2)
```

Comment: @polkovnikov.ph , I didn't ask this question but would be interested to see how this applied. The masters theorem link you mentioned seemed to be for recursive algorithms of the form T(n) = T(n/b) + F(n). How would you shape the complexity of the current problem in that form?

Comment: @polkovnikov.ph I thought of master method to calculate the complexity but how do i apply it here? It is not in the appropriate form that is T(n) = aT(n/b) + f(n)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: After reading the comments, maybe this is a simplifaction  / wrong. Would be interested as to exactly why though

```
O(n) + O(n-1) + O(n-2) + ... + O(1)

= O(n) + O(1) + O(n-1) +O(2) .... O(n-k + 1) + O(k)
```

where k = n /2

now

```
O(n - a) = O(n)
O(n) + O(a) = O(n)
```

so there are n/2 terms of :

O(n) + O(n) ....

```
so O(n^2)
```